# Why does the code with extension method compile?

Tags: scala, scala-cats

I have two functions:

```
  override def build_url(dbType: DbDriverType, dbAddr: String, dbName: String): F[DbAddr] = dbType match {
    case PostgresSql =>
      Applicative[F].pure(DbAddr("jdbc:postgresql://" |+| dbAddr |+| "/" |+| dbName))
    case _ => DbDriverError.raiseError[F, DbAddr]
  }

  override def get_db_driver(dbType: DbDriverType): F[DbDriver] = dbType match {
    case PostgresSql =>
      Applicative[F].pure(DbDriver("org.postgresql.Driver"))
    case _ => Applicative.raiseError[F, DbDriver](DbDriverError)
  }
```

The first compiles and the second not. The compiler complains:

```
[error]  found   : io.databaker.db.DbDriverError.type
[error]  required: cats.ApplicativeError[F, _ >: cats.Applicative.type]
[error]     case _ => Applicative.raiseError[F, DbDriver](DbDriverError)
```

On the first function, I use on `DbDriverError.raiseError[F, DbAddr]` the extension method and on the second not. For me, it should be the same.

What is the difference?

Comment: This is quite an interesting question. Can you try to make a reproducible example which doesn't need to define things like `DbDriverType` or provide simple mocks of them so copy and pasting would work? - BTW, concatenating strings can be very slow and inefficient in memory, I would recommend you to use a string interpolator instead: `s"jdbc:postgresql://${dbAddr}/${dbName}"`

Comment: Here is a proposal of how to reproduce the error: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/dah0s6gySOKorFwcgnjwPw/6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the second case `Applicative.raiseError[F, DbDriver](DbDriverError)` you are using extension method on `Applicative` compaion object. So this

```
Applicative.raiseError[F, DbDriver](DbDriverError)
```

is virtually this

```
new ApplicativeErrorIdOps[F, Applicative.type](Applicative).raiseError[DbDriver](DbDriverError)(implicitly[ApplicativeError[F, Applicative.type]])
```

Obviously there is no `ApplicativeError[F, Applicative.type]` instance, if your code is similar to @Luis Miguel Mejía Suárez's scastei, then there is `ApplicativeError[F, Throwable]` in the form of `Sync[F]`.

On the first example it works because `DbDriverError.raiseError[F, DbAddr]` is the extension method which performs

```
new ApplicativeErrorIdOps[F, DbDriverError.type](DbDriverError).raiseError[DbAddr](DbDriverError)(implicitly[ApplicativeError[F, DbDriverError.type]])
```

assuming that `object DbDriverError extends Exception` (or some other `Throwable`) it is equal to directly calling

```
implicitly[ApplicativeError[F, Throwable]].raiseError[DbAddr](DbDriverError)
```

where this implicit could also take `MonadError[F, Throwable]`, `Sync[F]` or any other implementeation of `ApplicativeError[F, Throwable]`. Since companions have summon method you could just write:

```
ApplicativeError[F, Throwable].raiseError[DbDriver](DbDriverError)
// not the same as
// Applicative.raiseError[F, DbDriver](DbDriverError)
// !!!
// See where are square brackets and type parameters!
// And the class doesn't even match!
```

TLDR:

`Applicative[F].sth` (calling `Applicative.apply[F[_]](implicit a: Applicative[F]): Applicative[F]` is not the same as `Applicative.sth` (calling method/extension method on `Applicative` companion object, especially if we need a method from `ApplicativeError` that isn't defined on `Applicative`).

Comment: One more question, what is a summon method?

Comment: A name for something that "summons" implicit, e.g. `Applicative` has `def apply[F[_]](implicit F: Applicative[F]): Applicative[F] = F` so that you can get an implicit by calling `Applicative[F]` (of course only if there is one available in the scope).